# Вывести массив без повторяющихся элементов

Tags: php

Я в PHP вобщем то новичок и у меня появилась задача в которой нужно сделать так, что бы на экран выводился "отфильтрованный" массив ссылок(то есть без повторений, использовал `array_unique`). Но когда вывожу один массив, то все равно есть повторяющиеся ссылки. Не понимаю что делаю не так, подскажите пожалуйста!

```
<?php
 include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

 $site='http://www.bonprix.ua';
 $html = file_get_html('http://www.bonprix.ua');


foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
   $str = $element->href;
   $str4 = substr($str, 0, 4);
   $arr_1 = array();
   $arr_2 = array();
   if ($str4 == 'http')
     {array_push($arr_1, $str. '<br>');}
   else
     {array_push($arr_2, $site.$element->href. '<br>');}

   $result = array_unique($arr_1);
   foreach($result as $value){echo $value;}
}
?>
```

Comment: Пример массива приведите. И укажите в нем повторяющиеся ссылки, которые остались после ваших манипуляций с array_unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему у вас не совсем правильное создание массива и вывод результата.
Добавление и вывод идут на каждой ссылке, хотя как я понял должны выводится после обработки всех ссылок.
По пробуйте вот так

```
$site='http://www.bonprix.ua';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.bonprix.ua');

$arr_1 = array();
$arr_2 = array();
foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
   $str = $element->href;
   $str4 = substr($str, 0, 4);

   if ($str4 == 'http')
     {array_push($arr_1, $str. '<br>');}
   else
     {array_push($arr_2, $site.$element->href. '<br>');}


}
$result = array_unique($arr_1);
foreach($result as $value){echo $value;}
?>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает, я понял свою ошибку! :)